# should this example not alter the memory address rather than the value at that memory address?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dereference, chars

In a book I am reading, C++ from scratch, on page 113 the writer creates a char array:

```
myString[80];
```

then he uses a function that copies some charectars:

```
strcpy(myString,"Hello there");
```

then he creates a pointer to the array:

```
*p1 = myString;
```

then he uses an offset and assings a value at that offset:

```
p1[4]='c';
```

my question is, p1 is a pointer so it is a memory address, and the offset of 4 gives him the memory address 4 spaces in front, so that means he is assingning the letter 'c' to the memory address rather than at the value stored at that address. Shouldnt it be:

```
*(p1[4])='c';
```

basically, how come *(p1 + 4) needs dereferencing but p1[4] does not?

I tried to understand this and the only thing that could make sense to me was if the square brackets act as an asterisk to dereference the pointer. Is this correct or is there another reason why p1[4] does not need to be dereferenced?

Comment: Why did you leave out the types? Please add them.

Comment: That book is almost twenty years old, by the way. Unless you're into retrocomputing you should consider getting one from this decade.

Comment: The [] operator returns a reference. Look up what it means and how it is used in c++ and I think you'll be ok.

Answer (score 3):

> then he creates a pointer to the array:
>
> ```
> *p1 = myString;
> ```

Assuming, by this, you actually mean that `p1` is declared and initialised using;

```
char *p1 = myString;
```

then your interpretation is wrong.   `p1` is a pointer to a `char` not a pointer to an array.

In this definition, `myString` is the (previously declared in your question) name of an array of `char`.   In the initialisation

```
char *p1 = myString;
```

the name `myString` is converted to a pointer.  That pointer will have the value `&myString[0]` (i.e. the address of the first character in `myString`).   That is the value that `p1` will receive.

The statement

```
 p1[4] = 'c';
```

will then set the fifth character (since indexing is zero based) of `myString` to be `'c'`.   The result is therefore changing `myString[4]` to the value `'c'`.   This means that (the first 11 characters of) `myString` will be `"Hellc there"`.

Assuming the above, the expression `*(p1[4])='c'` will not compile, since `(p1[4])` is of type `char`, and cannot be dereferenced using the `*` operator.

Semantically, in an expression `p1[4]` is equivalent to `*(p1 + 4)`.   Since `p1` is initialised to be equal to `&myString[0]`, `p1[4]` is ALSO equivalent to both `myString[4]` and to `*(myString + 4)`.

**Note:** If `*(p1[4])='c'` was valid in your code, then `p1[4] = 'c'` would not be valid, which suggests my assumption about the declaration and initialisation of `p1` is correct - despite the fact you have omitted such information.

Comment: I understand that: *(p1[4]) would not compile but I still don't think you have answered my question. What I was saying was that p1 is a memory address so if you do p1[4]='c' you are going to the memory address 4 spaces infront and assinging the charectar 'c' to the memory address rather than the value stored at that memory address

Comment: basically, how come when you do *(p1 + 4) you need to dereference it but when you do p1[4] you dont need to dereference it?

Comment: @AmeenIzhac You misunderstand something. There is *no difference* between `*(p1 + 4)` and `p1[4]` (if `p1` is a pointer). In fact, `p1[4]` is *defined* as `*(p1 + 4)`.

Comment: `p1[4]` is dereferencing.   It is specified as being equivalent in effect to `*(p1 + 4)`.

Answer (score 0):

`p1 + 4` would be the memory address 4 places beyond.

The expression `p1[4]` (exactly equivalent to `*(p1+4)`) is called an *lvalue* expression.  We say that an lvalue expression *designates* a memory location.  Or in other words, the lvalue expression is synonymous with the memory location itself.  You can always use the `&` address-of operator on an lvalue expression, and that gives you a pointer to the memory location.

The lvalue expression will go on to be used in one of three possible ways:

1. Store a value in the designated memory location, or
2. Retrieve a value from the designated memory location, or
3. Neither of those.

There is no special syntax to distinguish between these three cases; rather it depends on the larger expression of which the lvalue expression is a part of.  For example, applying the `&` operator is case 3;  appearing on the left-hand side of the assignment operator `=` is case 1.  Most other usages fall under case 2.

Answer (score -3):

`p1[4]` is treated as `*(p1 + 4)` which is "value at an offset of 4 from p1".

Also when you declare a char array:

```
myString[80]
```

myString is a pointer to the array (It points to the first element). So when you do `myString[4]` it is also treated as `*(myString + 4)`

Writing `*(p1[4])` would mean `*(*(p1 + 4))`

Comment: `myString` is not a pointer to the array.  It is the name of the array.   When `myString` is converted to a pointer (e.g. as happens when it is passed to `strcpy()`) the resulting pointer is equal to the address of the first element of `myString`.

Comment: "Writing *(p1[4]) would mean *(*(p1 + 4))", this isn't really true. The type of pointer comes into play here.

Comment: I think I have worded my question badly but what I was asking was basically how come you have to dereference: *(p1 + 4) to assign a value at that address but you dont have to dereference p1[4] to assign a value at that address